# Найти разницу в процентах между 2мя числами

Tags: javascript, математика, angularjs

Есть формула:

```
100*(y-x)/x
```

Да вычисляет вроде норм, к примеру x = 10, y = 20 показывает разницу в 100% все гуд. Но возьмем к примеру x = 10 000 000 y = 100, показывает -100% - не похоже на правду, минус должен быть явно меньшим чем ***-100***. Есть еще условие, что любое число может быть как положительным так и отрицательным.
[пример на Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qah4xwt/)

Comment: Может всё дело в `100.*(y-x)/x`?

Comment: ((y-x)/x) * 100 Так правильно

Comment: Разница в процентах от чего должна быть? если от x то разница будет -100% при округлении(x = 10 000 000 y = 100). Возможно стоит заменить на в процентах от минимального ?

Comment: Разница Y от X все верно.

Comment: Комментарий от @Shnur помог, но вот что в конце(последний ряд)  в примере происходит не понятно. См. скрин http://prntscr.com/a0zduv

Comment: @Fikret как уже сказал ранее `Batanicheck` там все верно, вы ведь считаете попроцентную разницу насколько X отличается от Y, т.е. будь бы у вас, например, 2 числа X = 10 и Y = 0, то то X бы отличался от Y на 100%, а ваш пример можно привести к такому виду: X = 10; Y = 0,0001, что составляет почти 100% (у вас же из-за целочисленной арифметики выдает 100, так что либо пользуетесь советом `Shnur` для получения ответа в виде числа с плавающей точкой, либо продолжаете считать в целых числах). Либо если необходимо считать относительно наименьшего, то просто меняйте местами аргументы.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо. Вопрос снят.

Comment: @Fikret Я продублировал комментарий в ответ дабы вопрос не висел в списке неотвеченных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже упоминалось ранее в комментариях, если вы считаете насколько попроцентно X отличается от Y, то ваша формула верна и выдает правильный ответ. 
Например, будь бы у вас 2 числа: `X = 10` и `Y = 0`, то то X бы отличался от Y на 100%, а ваш же пример можно привести к такому виду: `X = 10` и `Y = 0,0001`, что составляет почти 100% (у вас же, из-за целочисленной арифметики выдает `100%`, так что для получения ответа в виде числа с плавающей точкой, либо воспользуйтесь советом умножения на `double` (на `100.`, например), либо продолжаете считать в целых числах, если вам нужен именно целочисленный ответ). 
Вот если бы вы считали на сколько Y попроцентно отличается от X, то тогда бы уже ответ был действительно другим `100.0 * (10 000 000 - 100) / 100.0 == 9 999 900 %` (т.е. `100.0 * (X - Y) / Y`), т.е. если же необходимо считать относительно наименьшего из чисел (на сколько процентов отличается наименьшее число от наибольшего), то просто меняйте местами аргументы формулы (подставляйте в неё вместо `X` наименьшее число, а вместо `Y` наибольшее).